# SQL relations in NoSQL Schemas

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I need to design NoSQL Schemas (Mongoose) from next SQL Database.
[Image of SQL database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zGNa.png)

So I have a few questions about how to make those Schemas:

1. There is a field in table *course_student* called *entryDate*. In what Schema do I store this field and how do I connect it to other? (Refers to entry Date of one student to specific course) (Also the case for *startDate* in *course_teacher* table)
2. In Admin, Teacher and Student Schemas, how do I inherit all properties from PersonSchema (is this the case for Discrimantors?), or do I store all of their fields in PersonSchema (the case I don't like, because in case of "admin", teacher and student fields would be all NULL)
3. (Optional) Also, how to handle non-normalized case of many-many relationship? (Let's say there is no *course_teacher* table, and *teachers* & *courses* are connected with many-many relation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongo, like in SQL, there are many ways you can structure your data. The key to consider in Mongo, is how do you need to access the data. Try to group data in ways that it matches queries you expect to perform. Using that context, I'll try to answer some of your specific questions:

1) Your asking where to store the entryDate of a student into a class. Do you often pull students independently? Or do you always grab them with their classes? Do you need classes independently?

One option would be to nest classes inside of your students:
Student =>

```
{
   firstName: "John",
   lastName: "Smith",
   classes: [{
      classCode: "EN101",
      entryDate: "10/10/2017"
   }]
}
```

You could also have a class object with a list of students if you access it all it once usually:
Class =>

```
{
   classCode: "En101"
   students: [{
      studentId: 12345,
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Smith,
      entryDate: "10/10/2017"
   }]
}
```

If you often reference things separately, you could have a flat table like in your SQL that just has classCode, studentId, studentEntryDate

2. These objects are all stored together in one table? If so that sounds like a great use of discriminators. like if you just have a People collection. However, I would guess that they are stored separately? Teachers and Students are stored in different collections? In that case you can just have them inherit the same class in code, and they will serialize fine into mongo without any discriminators.
3. There's multiple ways to handle this. You could create collections for each table and maintain a linking table, but not usually the best way. I would think Teachers and Courses would be one-many not many-many? So each course would have a teacher. If courses do have many teachers, you can just have a list of teachers instead of a field called teacher.

Hope my answers are clear, feel free to comment for more information.

If your pretty new in Mongo, I recommend signing up for some of there free [courses](https://university.mongodb.com/). There pretty useful and get you a good foundation.

Good luck on your switch to mongo. It's worth it!

Comment: 1. In the first case of your code, how do I make that into a Schema by referencing? If I go like this: [Picture](https://imgur.com/CADQ4fB) wouldn't it think the field _entryDate_ is located in Course?
2. You are right, I would like to have different collection for teachers and students (and if possible, since they are all users, having them all under Person). How can I make them inherit fields from PersonSchema (without having to repeat each field inside Teacher and StudentSchema, only add new ones)

Comment: 3. It's designed so course can have multiple teachers. If I have inside CourseSchema teachers: [TeacherSchema], and inside TeacherSchema courses: [CourseSchema], wouldn't there be some errors, like what do I define first so it can have access to other?

Comment: MongoDB supports datetime types natively; use them, e.g.  
{  lastName:"Smith", entryDate: new ISODate("2017-09-29") }
This will provide superior queryability and sortability plus you will never run afoul of parsing problems and YYYYMMDD vs YYYYDDMM problems.

Comment: @Wolfdog, for 1, in your picture I think if you are going to put entryDate on the course object, you need to have it in a nested list of students. That way each student can have a different entry date. 2. I mostly code in .net, but I assume this transfers. I would have a Teacher and Student class, and both of them would inherit the PersonSchema. Each class would then get all the fields on PersonSchema, plus any additional fields defined. Mongo would then handle a save perfectly without any duplicate code.

Comment: For 3, its usually better just to put the reference in one of the many to many objects. I would probably just have a list of teachers on the CourseSchema. The teacher schema would not have a list of courses. If you need to know which courses a teacher is teaching, then you do a query on the courses object where the teachers array has that teacher in it. The array probably wouldn't be a TeacherSchema, but just the teacher's id. Or maybe new CourseTeacher class that just had a teacher id and their name.

Comment: @bgraham could u have a look at my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551101/assign-a-model-to-another-model) I am really sorry for bothering you...

Comment: No problem! Although I don't know mongoose well enough to give a specific answer. I generally code in .net. But you need to take control of the disciminator, which I think you are doing. Thats your UserSchema.role.type I think. In .net you need to register that with something called a BsonClassMapper, I'm not sure what the equivalent would be in mongoose.

Comment: Once you have control over the disciminator, you can change it as you please. user.role.type = 'teacher'. In C#, we need to create a new teacher object and map the fields over, I'm not sure if thats something you will need to do. But then mongo can will understand the new object is the same as the old object based on the id. Hope that helps, which I could give a more solid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below are two good resources with comparisons between RDBMS and NoSQL Databases.

https://www.mongodb.com/compare/mongodb-mysql

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-comparison/